# C# create form on separate thread from formless application

Tags: c#, winforms, signalr

I'm currently creating a formless C# application that will act as a SignalR client. The goal is for the client to run silently in the background and show a form when it is triggered by SignalR.

Currently, I'm having an issue showing the GUI. Since SignalR needs to run asynchronously, and I can't have an async `Main()` method, I currently have to use `Task.ContinueWith`

```
static void Main()
{
    _url = "https://localhost:44300";

    var hubConnection = new HubConnection(_url);
    var hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("HubName");

    hubConnection.Start().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error opening the connection");
        }
        else
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Connection established");
        }
    }).Wait();

    hubProxy.On("showForm", showForm);
    Application.Run();
}
```

This is the showForm method:

```
private static void ShowForm()
{
    var alertForm = new AlertForm();
    alertForm.Show();
}
```

This works fine at first - it connects to the hub, and calls the `showForm()` method when I call `showForm` from the server. However, the form never renders and shows as Not Responding. Calling `.ShowDialog` will mean the form actually renders, but the SignalR client stops listening to the hub.

So, how can I show the form such that it runs on a separate thread and doesn't block the execution of my SignalR client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is; although you create a message loop with *Application.Run* in *Main*, *hubProxy.On* is executed on a different thread.
Simplest solution would be running every instance of AlertForm in its own thread with its own message loop.

```
private static void ShowForm()
{
    var t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var alertForm = new AlertForm();
        alertForm.Show();
        Application.Run(alertForm); //Begins running a standard application message loop on the current thread, and makes the specified form visible.
    });
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start();
}
```